# "For my hand" vs. "for my part" vs. "for my side" in a cover letter?

Tags: word-choice

Writing a cover letter, which one would you choose when you are offering your services?

For example:

> For my [...], I offer a strong background in X and experience in Y.

Comment: Is this "offer" a charitable donation or the first bid in a deal? Are others involved? Are you going to say this with a warm smile or put it in a business letter?

Comment: business letter

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to preface the offer?  Are others contributing also?  That's how I'd imagine the need for the statement, ***"For my part, I'm contributing..."*** Otherwise If you are just individually offering something, I'd say, ***"I'm offering a ..."***

Comment: Kristina, is "For my part" similar to "As far as I can" in your context?

Comment: @Carlo_R., not in my context, I meant mine to define my contribution, independent of someone else's additional contribution.